# Python -'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

When I run this code, it reveals that "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in the line if m[x][i] > mini:
and i dont know why.
i passed X (x = 0) and use the i in t
    import random

```
def llenarmatriz(m, filas, columnas):
    for i in range(filas):
        m.append([0] * columnas)
    for i in range(filas):
        for j in range(columnas):
            m[i][j] = random.randint(0, 99)
    for i in range(filas):
        for j in range(columnas):
            print("%3d" % m[i][j], end="")
        print()


def procesarmatrizfila(m, filas, columnas, x):
    maxi = 10000000000000
    mini = maxi * -1
    for i in range(columnas):
        if m[x][i] > mini:
            mini = m[x][i]
            fm = i
    for i in range(filas):
        if m[i][x] <= maxi:
            maxi = m[i][x]
            fmin = i
    return mini, fm, maxi, fmin


m = []
n = int(input("Igresar numero: "))
columnas = filas = n
m = llenarmatriz(m, filas, columnas)
x = 0
while x < filas:
    mini, fm, maxi, fmin = procesarmatrizfila(m, filas, columnas, x)
    print("Fila numero: %d" % x)
    print("el valor maximo es: %d y esta en la posicion: %d %d" %      (mini, x, fm))
print("el valor minimo es: %d y esta en la posicion: %d %d" % (maxi, x, fmin))
x = x + 1
```

Comment: So what's this code supposed to do? We can't fix your bug if we don't know how the code is *intended* to behave. Describing the desired behavior of your program is part of providing a [mcve].

Comment: Minimal reproduction case: `None[1]`. So *where* (in exactly *which* `[..`]) and *why* does the code have None for a value? That's called "debugging".. it's because `m` is None or `m[x]` has not been assigned something appropriate yet (and is `None`); follow 'follow the code/expectations' backward from there..

Comment: Suggest you focus on learning how to debug.

Comment: Thanks! to all, im doing my first steps in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m = llenarmatriz(m, filas, columnas)
```

here you does not return anything from function so m becomes nonetype 
to fix this error

```
def llenarmatriz(m, filas, columnas):
    for i in range(filas):
        m.append([0] * columnas)
    for i in range(filas):
        for j in range(columnas):
            m[i][j] = random.randint(0, 99)
    for i in range(filas):
        for j in range(columnas):
            print("%3d" % m[i][j], end="")
        print()
    return m
```